# Thymeleaf and yarn

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yarnpkg, mermaid

I would like to use mermaid in my spring boot project.

https://mermaidjs.github.io/usage.html

The usage description tells me to use yarn add mermaid.
Can anyone explain me, what exactly I have to configure in my spring boot / thymeleaf project in order to use this dependency in my frontend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just download from or use the CDN (https://unpkg.com/mermaid@7.1.2/dist/mermaid.min.js) to get the required files using standard `<link>` and `<script>` tags. Yarn is a front end dependency manager and I presume you have not separated your front end from you Spring Boot application.

Comment: This is correct, my issue is that I would like to use the mermaidAPI which seems not to be included in the mermaid.min.js - or am I completely confused?

Comment: Could you explain how to add ecmascript sources?

Comment: I'm not too sure on that but you can use webjars dependency, put `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>github-com-knsv-mermaid</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
        </dependency>` in your pom and then access the files from [yourdomain]/webjars/github-com-knsv-mermaid/7.0.3/src/mermaidAPI.js

Comment: After further investigation don't use the above but I'll go back to a cdn from: <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/7.0.0/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/knsv/mermaid/7.0.0/dist/mermaid.css"> Ig ot a working example using this